# Reference variable not returning value in c++

Tags: c++, function, variables, reference

I am having a problem with my reference variable storing the values in my function. Where am I going wrong with this code?

```
//Loads temperature from a disk file and outputs them to the screen

#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include "myHeader.h"
using namespace std;

//Function prototypes
void minMax (int mean[], int size, int &, int &);

//Declare Global variables
string userFile;         //variable for user input of file
string date;             //variable for inputFile date
int low;                 //variable for inputFile low
int high;                //variable for inputFile high
double sumLow = 0.0;     //variable to hold sum of low temps
double sumHigh = 0.0;    //variable to hold sum of high temps
ifstream inputFile;

const int ARRAY_SIZE = 31;
int lowTemp[ARRAY_SIZE];
int highTemp[ARRAY_SIZE];

//Accumulators
int min = 200;
int max = 0;
int count = 0;
int minTemp = 0;
int maxTemp = 0;

int main()
{
//Call the heading function
heading(8, 'A');

//Prompt user to enter a file
cout << "What file do you want to open for input? ";
cin >> userFile;
cout << endl; 

inputFile.open(userFile);

minMax(lowTemp, ARRAY_SIZE, minTemp, maxTemp);

//Close the file
inputFile.close();

return 0;
}

//******************************************
//Definition of function minMax
//******************************************

void minMax (int mean[], int size, int & min, int & max)
{

    for (int i = 0; (i < ARRAY_SIZE) && (inputFile >> date >>     low >> high); i++)
    {
        lowTemp[i] =  low;
        highTemp[i] = high;
        count = i;
        sumLow += lowTemp[i];
        sumHigh += highTemp[i];

        if (lowTemp[i] < min)
        {
            min = lowTemp[i];
        }
        if (highTemp[i] > max)
        {
            max = highTemp[i];
        }

        minTemp = min;
        maxTemp = max;
    }

    cout << "array size " << count + 1 <<  " array low " << minTemp << " array high " << maxTemp << endl << endl;
    cout << endl << count + 1 << " " << sumLow << " " << sumHigh << endl;
}
```

The program compiles and ask the user which file to open. I enter the file and it returns.

array size 31 array low 0 array high 91

31 1831 2602

The array High is correct; however , the array low should be 34 according to the file.

Comment: Have you tried coming up with an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org)?  Generally dumping code on StackOverflow and asking people to debug it is frowned upon.  It sounds like you should be able to reproduce your problem in just a few lines (e.g. no need to read input (just hardcode your test case), or size/High calculations).  Often by doing this you'll find you resolve the problem yourself anyway...

Answer (score 2):

Low is initialized to zero: `int minTemp = 0;`

---

May I recommend to read a good text book? Your code reads like you do not understand what is happening.

Many of your global variables are unused, as they are hidden by local parameters with the same name. Removing the global variables or replacing them by local variables will improve your code quality.

E.g.

```
//Accumulators
int min = 200;
int max = 0;

....

void minMax (int mean[], int size, int & min, int & max)
{
```

The global `min` and `max`, what you call "accumulators," are totally unusused.

Comment: You're passing in `minTemp` (0) into `minMax`, by reference, as `min`. On each iteration, your code checks `if (lowTemp[i] < min)`. None of the values are less than 0.

Comment: Thanks it works perfect now. Didn't realize I had to initilize both variables to a higher number in order to store the value.

Comment: The book Im having to use is starting out with C++ by Tony Gaddis, it kinda just skims over reference variables.